# A question about holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

If $f\in H(U)$, i.e. $f$ is holomorphic on $U  \subset \Bbb C$ and $U$ is open in $\Bbb C$, and let $z \in U$ be fixed.

Define: $$F(\xi)=\frac{f(\xi)-f(z)}{\xi - z}$$ if $\xi \in U-\{z\}$ , and $$F(\xi)=f'(z)$$ if $\xi=z$.

I'm wondering why $F\in H(U-\{z\})$, which means $F$ is not holomorphic at point $z$

Should I check its partial derivative or check the Cauchy Riemann equation?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: $F\in H(U-\{z\})$ does *not* mean $F$ is not differentiable at $z$ - it says nothing about the behaviour of $F$ at the point $z$ at all. Are you sure you have not misread something?

Comment: In my book the definition of $f$ is holomorphic if $f$ is $C^1$ and satisfies Cauchy Reimann equation.

Comment: Or should I prove that partial derivative does not exists？

Comment: As said by ancientmathematician, you're not requested to deal with point $z$ but with points $\xi \in \mathbb C \setminus \{z\}$. You should apply the holomorphic definition you were given for those points. For example saying that $\{3, 4, \dots \}$ are integers doesn't mean that $1$ is not.

Comment: Yes to your definition, but $F$ holomorphic on $U-\{z\}$ does not mean $F$ is not differentiable at $z$. In this question why do you say $F'(z)$ does not exist? Try the case $f(\zeta)=\zeta$ with the point $z=0$. You'll find $F'(0)=0$.

Comment: The reason why I have this question is that I am reading the proof of Cauchy integral formula and the author define this function $F$, and he says $F$ is continuous on the open disk but not holomorphic on a point $z$ in the open disk. It looks like $F$ is not holomorphic on the entire open disk, which means $F$ is not holomorphic at $z$.

Comment: Do you know the Riemann theorem on removable singularities? It shows that $F$ is indeed holomorphic in $U$.

Comment: Sorry, not yet.